# Grouping ands and ors in AREL

Tags: sql, ruby, arel

I'm trying to query the equivalent of this sql snippet using arel:

```
WHERE (("participants"."accepted" = 'f' AND "participants"."contact_id" = 1) 
  OR "participants"."id" IS NULL)
```

So I want `(accepted && contact_id=1) OR NULL`

Here's what I've got in AREL

```
participants[:accepted].eq(false).and(participants[:contact_id].eq(1).
  or(participants[:id].is(nil)
```

Problem is, this generates:

```
("participants"."accepted" = 'f' AND "participants"."contact_id" = 1 OR "participants"."id" IS NULL)
```

Note the lack of parentheses around my and conditions.  I *believe* that according to the operator precedence, that I'm getting:

```
accepted && (contact_id=1 OR NULL)
```

Adding parentheses in in the AREL query has no affect.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I believe that according to the operator precedence

The problem is that [AND has higher precedence than OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx). So `1 AND 2 OR 3` is equivalent to `(1 AND 2) OR 3`.

As a side note: if you use a wrapper like [this one](https://gist.github.com/tokland/1333253), you can write:

```
User.where((User[:created_at] > 3.days.ago) & (User[:enabled] == true))
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what Arel gives you. How is it too low-level?

Comment: Squeel looks great, though (I hadn't known about it). But calling it less low-level than Arel isn't really accurate -- it's just a syntax modification.

Comment: Given the context, it is not clear to me that "low level" is meant to refer to the library as a whole -- it looks like it's more meant to refer to the internals that Aaron was writing.

Comment: And no, "low level" and "high level" are not subjective, at least as relative terms. You said Squeel was higher level than Arel. So far as I can tell, it is just a syntax mod of Arel, and therefore works on the exact same level. The exception would be sifters, which abstract Arel and therefore work at a higher level.

Comment: mmm... ya you're right.  I was actually trying to translate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN participants` written by hand to use `includes(:participants)`.  Problem is I have additional conditions on my join.  So I was hoping I could just tack them into a `where` but they don't see to be equivalent.  Have to modify my question

Comment: ugh, I'm doubly messing up here, the reason I thought this was failing was because my previously written tests were failing, (the actual query is a bit more complex)  But it was failing because I refactored `!=` in the sql to `.eq` in the arel...  oops.

Comment: thx for the wrapper suggestion btw!  I actually like working with ARel, I find I can do more complex queries than ActiveRecord allows for, that wrapper syntax is kind of nice though, I generally just use `arel_table`

Answer (score 31):

You can generate parentheses using [`Arel::Nodes::Grouping`](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb).

```
participants = Arel::Table.new("participants")

arel = participants.grouping(
  participants[:accepted].eq(false).and(participants[:contact_id].eq(1))
).or(participants[:id].eq(nil))

arel.to_sql # => (("participants"."accepted" = 'f' AND "participants"."contact_id" = 1) OR "participants"."id" IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, .grouping worked great. Instead of `participants = Arel::Table.new("participants")`, I used `participants = Participant.arel_table`

Comment: This solution works elegantly and solves the issue at hand. This would be my preferred answer to the problem. Great options all around though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not flip them around. Should be equivalent to:

```
participants[:id].is(nil).or(participants[:accepted].eq(false).and(participants[:contact_id].eq(1))
```

hopefully I've got the parens properly set in the above, but you see what I mean...

Comment: Ya I think I was wrong about needing this, Tokland is right, the precedence is not my problem, it's actually that my query is different than what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that allows you to use existing AR methods such as `where` and perhaps any existing scopes, etc in your code.  So it's easy to reuse existing AR code with Arel as needed.

```rb
class Participant
  scope :grouped, -> {
    group1 = arel_table.grouping(where(accepted: false, contact_id: 1).arel.constraints)
    group2 = arel_table.grouping(where(id: nil).arel.constraints)

    where(group1.or(group2))
  }
end
```

This works in Rails 7, and perhaps Rails 6.x as well.